# Changing functionality of back button on android

Tags: android

I want to change the functionality of back button for a particular bunch of code being active. Once its done how do i reset it to default.

I am using following piece of code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && issearchopen)
        {               
            searchView.closeSearch();
        }

        else{

        }
        return true;
    }
```

boolean `issearchopen` is true whenever my 'bunch' of code is active.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to override the `onBackPressed()` in the Activity.

Comment: how is it going to help me?

Comment: i have successfully done as you said but how do i reset the default functionality?

Comment: Posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(isSearchOpen){
     // do stuff
   } else {
      super.onBackPressed(); // default behaviour
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it you need to override `onBackPressed()` method.
Your code will looks like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(issearchopen){
      searchView.closeSearch();
      issearchopen = false;
   } else {
      super.onBackPressed(); // default back press behaviour
   }
}
```

Also don't forget to change `issearchopen` to `true` when open searchView.